# GuidedStepFragment option is editable by default

Tags: android, android-tv

I tried to use GuidedStepFragment to organize settings of my tv app. I run into with problem, that step option work like EditText field, but I don't use GuidedAction.Builder.editable() method.

Settings fragment code

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends GuidedStepSupportFragment {

    @Override
    public GuidanceStylist.Guidance onCreateGuidance(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = "Настройки1";
        String description = "Настройки2";
        String breadcrumb = "Настройки3";
        Drawable icon = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon_quantum);
        return new GuidanceStylist.Guidance(title, description, breadcrumb, icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateActions(@NonNull List<GuidedAction> actions,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        actions.add(new GuidedAction.Builder()
                    .id(1)
                    .infoOnly(true)
                    .title("Адрес сервера")
                    .build());
    }
}
```

How I add fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GuidedStepSupportFragment.add(getSupportFragmentManager(), new SettingsFragment());
}
```

- Android Studio version: Beta 4
- Gradle plugin version: 2.0.0-beta4
- Build tools version: 23.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I notice that these bug appears only when app running on tablet, or I try to navigate via mouse on emulator.